# How to create a menu with Images in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm trying to modify the `GameState Management Sample from Microsoft` [here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) to have a menu that uses `textures` instead of `text`, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Simply passing a `Texture2D` to the `MenuEntry` class don't work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

You can add rectangles and then texture those rectangles, either create a texture with the text or just place the text over the rectangles but change the bounds to be the rectangle instead of the text.

I have not played around with that much but it shouldn't be too bad.

There is a game scene manager on Youtube I found that seems pretty decent it might be worth a look also has free download.

Hope this helps!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTxdOWC_Ytc